# Can't import external NPM package to make angular library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, typeerror

- `package.json` firstly I did this,

```
{
  "name": "crypto-local-storage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.8",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Secondly, I did this

```
{
  "name": "crypto-local-storage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.8",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

But in my service file when I import `secure-web-storage`  Like this

`import * as SecureStorage from 'secure-web-storage';` 
I got this kinda message,

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'secure-web-storage'.
 'D:/AMS/crypto-local-storage/projects/crypto-local-storage/node_modules/secure-web-storage/secure-storage.js' 
implicitly has an 'any' type.  
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/secure-web-storage` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 
`declare module 'secure-web-storage';`
```

`secure-web-storage` does not contain any `@types/secure-web-storage` file. So How could I get rid from this error ? I did not get any clear answer after googling so much.

My folder structure might be help you,

[My Folder Structure Image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37630292/139533532-0f3beb48-b1cb-4c1a-9a3f-33073d33024b.png)

Comment: Have you tried to do  what the TypeScript compiler suggested?

Comment: @tromgy yes, but till now getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running `npm install -D @types/secure-web-storage` didn't solve the problem use `require` instead of `import`.

```
const secureWebStorage= require('secure-web-storage');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to create a `typings.d.ts` file inside the src folder and manually add typings for it.

```
declare module 'secure-web-storage' {
    export function someFunction(): void;
}
```

And then in your ts file, you can use something like -

```
import { someFunction } from 'secure-web-storage';
```

By using this method you can save a lot on bundle size instead of using -

```
const secureWebStorage= require('secure-web-storage');
```

which takes a lot of bundle size and makes the application slower. You can read more about this here - https://web.dev/commonjs-larger-bundles/